# How to Update 0 stock in eBay using perl (eBay API)?

Tags: xml, perl, ebay-api

I would like to create a script in perl/c++ that would change my quantity on eBay to 0 at 4am and to 5 at 1pm everyday and this should happen automatically. I found that I was able to connect to my eBay account through the script but was not able to edit the quantity.

I am getting a syntax error on this part. I have used `ReviseInventoryStatusRequest`

```
    # define the HTTP header
my $objHeader = HTTP::Headers->new;
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL' => '391');
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME' => 'dev id to be given here');
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME' => 'app id to be given here');
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME' => 'cert id to be given here');
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME' => 'GeteBayOfficialTime');
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-SITEID' => '0');
$objHeader->push_header('Content-Type' => 'text/xml');

# define the XML request
my $request =
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" .
    "<GeteBayOfficialTimeRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">" .
    "  <RequesterCredentials>" .
    "    <eBayAuthToken>my token here
</eBayAuthToken>" .
    "  </RequesterCredentials>" .
    "</GeteBayOfficialTimeRequest>";

my $inventory=
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" .
"<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">" .
  "<RequesterCredentials>" .
    "   <eBayAuthToken>My token here
</eBayAuthToken>" .
 " <InventoryStatus>" .
   " <ItemID>262906308587</ItemID>" .
    "<Quantity>0</Quantity>" .
  "</InventoryStatus>" .
"</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>";


# make the call
my $objRequest = HTTP::Request->new(
  "POST",
  "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll",
  $objHeader,
  $request,
$inventory
);

# deal with the response
my $objUserAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $objResponse = $objUserAgent->request($objRequest);
if (!$objResponse->is_error) {
  print $objResponse->content;
}
else {
  print $objResponse->error_as_HTML;
}
```

Would be great if someone could suggest how to edit this code or any other code that can be used to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: You forgot the opening quote on line 3, `<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest`. But just adding a double quote there won't work because your XML contains double quotes. Use [`q//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#q/_STRING_/) or a [here-doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3C_EOF_) instead.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ok that is not the only problem. You didn't get the point. I want to know if this will work. for example, if I run my code every one hour and the time is 4 am will the quantity change to 0 with this kind of code? That is what I want to know... code edited please check again. $request is working but the same type of code is there for $inventory and that gives me an error

Comment: I didn't get the point because the only code you showed in your original question had a syntax error, which I pointed out for you. Now you're asking a completely different question about completely different code. But my first comment still applies: you didn't escape the double quotes in your XML. Escape them with backslashes as you did when you declared `$request`, or use `q//` or a here-doc (my preference).

Answer (score 2):

eBay is not allow to set 0 Quantity in **eBay SendBox Account**.

In eBay Production account you can set 0 Quantity and product will not visible for customer.If you search product via item-id then you can see product status is **OUT Of Stock**.

In eBay Production account there is one configuration for **OUT Of Stock** Product.

You can do via Manually Configuration or API.

1. Go to eBay **Seller account** >> **SetUserPreferences** >> set **OutOfStockControlPreference** True.
2. eBay Provide API **SetUserPreferences** as well.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <SetUserPreferencesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"> 
     <RequesterCredentials>
       <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
     </RequesterCredentials>
     <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel> 
     <SellerPaymentPreferences>
       <OutOfStockControlPreference>true</OutOfStockControlPreference>
     </SellerPaymentPreferences>
   </SetUserPreferencesRequest>
   ```

If in eBay production account **OutOfStockControlPreference** is False then also you are not allow to update 0 stock in eBay.

You can refer eBay API using following link.

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/SetUserPreferences.html#Samples